# Why does sendAsync HttpClient work sequentially if I'm not do collect inbetween?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-http-client, java-17

During doing a tutorial about JDK11 `HttpClient`, using a `https://httpstat.us/500?sleep=1000` endpoint which is returning `HTTP 500` after 1 second, I prepared the following piece of code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

var futures = Stream.of(
        "https://httpstat.us/500?sleep=1000",
        "https://httpstat.us/500?sleep=1000",
        "https://httpstat.us/500?sleep=1000"
).map(link -> client
        .sendAsync(
                newBuilder(URI.create(link)).GET().build(),
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding()
        ).thenApply(HttpResponse::statusCode)
).collect(Collectors.toList());

futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).forEach(System.out::println);
```

and it is working fine. Program execution takes ~1.5s, output is being rendered in terminal at the same time for all three calls - everything is good.

But when I'm changing this to

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

Stream.of(
        "https://httpstat.us/500?sleep=1000",
        "https://httpstat.us/500?sleep=1000",
        "https://httpstat.us/500?sleep=1000"
).map(link -> client
        .sendAsync(
                newBuilder(URI.create(link)).GET().build(),
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding()
        ).thenApply(HttpResponse::statusCode)
).map(CompletableFuture::join).forEach(System.out::println);
```

it seems to not be working async anymore - three `500` are being shown one by one with 1 second delay before each.

Why? What am I missing here?

Comment: Because that’s how a stream works. It’s waiting for each iteration to complete before proceeding to the next.

Comment: I understand but why doing a collect inbetween is changing this behaviour?

Comment: Also I see that, indeed, if I will add `.parallel()` after `Stream.of(...)` it's again working properly - so it must be because of Java sequential streams

Comment: Because you don’t `join` when you `Collect` - so it runs all the requests and puts the promises in a list. Adding `parallel` is silly as you run a bunch of async requests and then have a bunch of threads blocking on waiting for those async requests - it’s a pointless waste of resources; it could also deadlock as they’re using the same thread pool.

Comment: you are right - when I'm moving `map(...join)` before collect output is being rendered at the same time but execution takes ~3s. And thanks a lot about additional explanation about `parallel` :) If you'd like to move this comment to answer I'd like to accept this

Comment: @BoristheSpider the ForkJoin pool has a deadlock prevention in this specific case. But it can result in the creation of even more threads, so it’s still a “pointless waste of resources”, as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `map` method on a Java `Stream` is an *"intermediate operation"*, and therefore *lazy*. This means the `Function` passed to it is not invoked on the elements of the stream until something downstream from it consumes the element.

This is described in the JavaDoc section called ["Stream operations and pipelines"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) (with my comments added in square brackets):

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as `filter()` [or `map()`] does not actually perform any filtering [or mapping], but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate [or are transformed by the given function in the case of `map()`]. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

In this case, it means that the requests aren't made until the stream is consumed.

In the first example, `collect()` is the *terminal operation* that consumes the stream. The result is a list of `CompletableFuture` objects that represent the running requests.

In the second example, `forEach` is the terminal operation that consumes each element of the stream, one by one. Because the `join` operation is contained within that stream, each `join` completes before the element is passed on to `forEach`. Subsequent elements are consumed sequentially, and therefore each request is not even made until the prior request completes.